# How to save term to file in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

How can I save necessary terms to file?
For example,

```
save_to_file(File) :-
    tell(File),
    listing,         
    told.
```

saves all user terms to file `File`.
But how can I save only necessary terms to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of safe_to_file/1 is safer using [`open/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=open/3) and [`close/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=close/1).
Otherwise, interrupts or errors happening during listing/0 would
leave the stream open, permitting other parts to write to the same file accidentally.
So,

```
save_to_file(File) :-
   open(File,write,Stream),
   with_output_to(Stream, listing),
   close(Stream).
```

is safer. Now, only listing can write to that file. [`with_output_to/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=with_output_to/2)
is specific to SWI, YAP.

To come back to your question, in most situations,
portray_clause(Stream, Term) will be what you actually want.

Comment: But what should I do to save all similar terms, such as likes(john, apples), likes(mike, oranges), likes(mary, cabbage)?

Comment: Just alter listing above.  So, instead of listing, you can substitute listing(likes) or if you want to be more specific, listing(likes/2)

Comment: @qutron: Ah, so what you want is not to save a term, but to save a select predicate to a file.